# Can't input data into input field from VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to set the values on multiple input fields using a WebBrowser control.

```
    <input type="text" name="Customer" maxlength="80" value=""         style="background:#DCE4EF;width:100;border: 1px solid #2B589B">
```

I know I can't use WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById as i has no id. I need to do this three times on three different input fields with different names. Is it possible and if so how can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you give us some code that you have used or tried? It's easier to edit than to go from scratch.

Comment: Can you not get it by anything other than Id? Maybe iterate through all Tag Names and get the one you want that way?

Comment: I've tried other things. I know how to grab information from things that aren't a div but putting information in is something I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

change name="Customer" to id="Customer" then use `document.GetElementById`

```
string str = "new value"
```

once you have the element `element.SetAttribute("value", str)`
also you could leave name="Customer" and use `document.All.GetElementsByName("Customer")[0].SetAttribute("value", str)`

Comment: That would work if I had access to the HTML. I can't change it.

Comment: I'm assumming that it's an external webpage and you can do that using the second document.All.GetElementsByName("Customer") collection of all elements with the name Customer, If the element  is the only element with the name Customer then you can just use [0] if not you will need to iterate through the collection until you find the correct index [0], [3], [7] etc.etc. If it is the only one in that collection it will always be the 0 index [0]. so you could obtain this element with document.All.GetElementsByName(Customer)[0] then just use the SetAttribute on that element.

Comment: It's saying Identifier Expected?

Comment: show me the exact code your using? on the SetAttribute(string attributeName, string value) the string attributeNme should be value and string value should be the new Customer(name id whatever the case that will display in the input text field) in this case

Comment: example i dont use vb but c# so not familar with but will explain best i can in a way that i think you will get the hint.const string attrName = "value" string myNewCustomer = "Crystal Wolf" document.All.GetElementsByName("Customer")[0].SetAttribute(attrName, myNewCustomer) the attrName on a link would be href instead of value if that makes sense.

Comment: How did it work out for you? If you need more help getting the solution to work let me know and I'll be more than happy to help. If this solved your dilemma pleas mark solved and consider an upvote thanks

Comment: I'm not sufficient with C# to VB.net conversion and so, haven't been able to get this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any attribute with this code:

```
Dim AllElementes As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
 For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In AllElementes
     If webpageelement.GetAttribute("name") = "Customer" Then
         webpageelement.SetAttribute("value","YOUR TEXT HERE")
     End If     
Next
```

you can change `"name"` to any other element in any tag.

But if it is like this:

```
<h1>text here</h1>
```

Refer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817813/how-to-get-any-text-into-webbrowser-document-without-get-any-attribute-vb-net/36821453#36821453).