# how to get any text into WebBrowser Document without get any Attribute ? vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

how to get any text into WebBrowser Document without get any Attribute in vb.net?!

example1:

```
<h1>text here</h1>
```

example2:

```
<h1 name="anything">text here</h1>
```

how can i get "text here" ?!

thanks. :)

Comment: I can't help but notice that you've been online. Have my answer been of any usefulness? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could either **1)** Use the WebBrowser's built-in methods to iterate through all `<h1>` tags or get the very first one, or **2)** Use a Regex.

**Using the built-in methods**

Iterating though all tags is simple, you just have to use the `HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName()` method.

Getting the first found tag (chronologically):

```
Dim h1Text As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h1")(0).InnerText
```

Iterating through all tags:

```
Dim h1Strings As New List(Of String)

For Each h1Tag As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h1")
    h1Strings.Add(h1Tag.InnerText)
Next
```

---

**Using a Regex**

Using a Regex is not that hard if you know what you are doing. To start with put this `Imports` statement on the very top of your code file:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Now you just have to search the WebBrowser's `DocumentText` for the `<h1>` tag.

```
Dim h1Text As String = Regex.Match(WebBrowser1.DocumentText, "(?<=<h1[^<>\/]*>)((?!<\/h1>).)*(?=<\/h1>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value
```

The Regex pattern explained:

`(?<=<h1[^<>\/]*>)((?!<\/h1>).)*(?=<\/h1>)`

`(?<= ...)`: The matched text must be preceded with whatever `...` is.

`<h1[^<>\/]*>`: Match the `<h1>` opening tag with any attributes.

`[^<>\/]*`: Match all characters that are not `<`, `>` or `/`.

`((?!<\/h1>).)*`: Match all characters that *are not* preceded by an `</h1>` tag.

`(?=<\/h1>)`: The match must
be followed by a `</h1>` tag.

Comment: If this works for you, please remember to mark as the accepted answer by pressing the green check mark on the left of the post.